# How to use manim from any directory in windows

Tags: python, path-variables, manim

I am trying to execute command `python -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl` from any directory in my windows machine. It works fine when I execute the command in the root directory of manim library(directory which contains requirement.txt, README.md and all those stuff). I tried to edit the path environment variable of my system but it still does not work.

ERROR -

`C:\Users\succu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: No module named manim`

I am sure that I have edited my path variable correctly because I can call out README.md and requirements.txt files in manim root directory from and location.

How can I solve this issue? My python version is 3.8.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with your installation, what happens is that you are using Manim locally, when you run:

```
python -m manim ...
```

Is the same as:

```
python manim.py ...
```

That is, you are executing the manim.py module (the file) which is in a local copy of Manim, and therefore you cannot move it.
The best way to solve it is to create a virtual environment, either with virtualenv or Anaconda, install the Manim dependencies again and install Manim to the Path of that virtual environment.
If you use virtualenv it would be:

```
# Install virtualenv
C:\...\> python -m pip install virtualenv

# Move to some safe place, where that it will not be eliminated
C:\...\> cd C:\save_place...\

# Create and activate a virtual env
C:\save_place...\> virtualenv manimenv
C:\save_place...\> .\manimenv\Source\activate
(manimenv) C:\save_place...\> 

# Download here the repo and install it
(manimenv) C:\save_place...\> pip install -e .

# Try run manim - You don't need the 'python -m manim', only 'manim'
(manimenv) C:\save_place...\> manim example_scenes.py WriteStuff -pl
```

And thats it, the advantage of this is that the `manim` command will only be available in your virtual environment, and you will have to activate it every time you need it.

More info: **Learn to use virtualenv**

Comment: Thank You. I am trying to learn `manim` from your youtube videos.